# Stubbing Out Instance Methods In MiniTest

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, minitest

I have a handful of instance methods I need to stub out before I test an assertion within the context of MiniTest.

Would there be a way to accomplish this out of the box?

The examples I've come across all seem to be related to just stubbing out one method and then passing a block to be executed within the stubbed context

Comment: There's [whole libraries for this](https://github.com/freerange/mocha). Which ones are you familiar with?

Comment: Had wound up having mocha recommended by another friend--thanks for the tip here as well!

If you want to add mocha as an answer, happy to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's libraries like [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) which are intended to make stubbing and mocking a lot easier. These give you tools which help defining them, and if necessary, later testing that certain methods were executed.